# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. PHP error

Tags: php

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\classes\DB.php on line 21

Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\classes\DB.php on line 21
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

It gives me this error when its on XAMPP, but when i put it on a live server it works fine, I know the DB credentials are correct, I am using the current version of XAMPP (as of yesterday)  for windows and using Apache 2 on the live server, both with MySql.

Line 18-25:

```
// Takes values from 'config.php' and uses them to connect
private function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('msql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

And this is where the array is set:

```
// Sets the config valuses
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'password',
        'db' => 'site'
    ), 
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800
    ), 
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user'
    ) 
);
```

And the config class:

```
class Config {
    public static function get($path = null) {
        if($path) {
            $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
            $path = explode('/', $path);

            foreach($path as $bit) {
                if(isset($config[$bit])) {
                    $config = $config[$bit];
                }
            }

            return $config;
        }

        return false;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Try to `var_dump(Config::get('msql/host'))` (as well as the other ones) to see what you get.  Clearly, (at least) one of them is an array.

Comment: Got rid of the error, but a new one poped up, "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\classes\DB.php on line 21".

Comment: Did you add a `;` after the `var_dump` line?

Comment: `$this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . var_dump(Config::get('msql/host')) . ';dbname=' . var_dump(Config::get('mysql/db')), var_dump(Config::get('mysql/username')), var_dump(Config::get('mysql/password'));`

Comment: \*facepalm* [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump) is a *debugging* tool.  It will print out the contents of the variable passed to it.  It should help you see what each of the `Config::get()` calls are returning.

Comment: its what it should be `string(9) "127.0.0.1"`

Comment: Then try to `var_dump()` the other ones, maybe one of them isn't what you think it is.  `var_dump(Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));`.

Comment: All correct, exactly what i set them. `string(9) "127.0.0.1" string(4) "site" string(4) "root" string(8) "password"`

Comment: Strange.  Just as a sanity check, what does `echo 'mysql:host=' . Config::get('msql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db');` show?

Comment: `Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 11
mysql:host=Array;dbname=site`

Comment: There's the issue.  `Config::get('msql/host')` is returning an array, not a string.

Answer (score 2):

Typos:

```
    $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('msql/host') . ';dbname=' . 
                                                       ^^^^^---no Y

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
      ^---has a Y
```

Comment: Didn't get rid of this error, but thanks, its late and i can barely think straight.

Comment: $dbhost = "localhost:3306"; 
adding the MySQL port worked for me

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->_pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".config::get('mysql/host').";dbname=".config::get('mysql/database') ,config::get('mysql/user'),config::get('mysql/password'));
```

Please check! Is there any space between `"mysql:host=".config::get('mysql/host')."`? I was getting the same error because of space!

Comment: This was my problem! I had put a space between "host=[hostname]" and "dbname=[database]" instead of a semicolon. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$dbhost = "localhost:3306"; adding the MySQL port worked for me

Comment: This solved by problem.

I made a typo and used ,port=yyy (instead of ;port=yyy) to add the port, which messed up the hostname!